# How to insert message at the beginning of an Azure storage queue?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues, azure-storage-emulator

How can we insert messages to the front of a Azure storage queue (essentially using it as a stack for the messages inserted in the queue front) ?

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer to your question is that you can't control the order in which messages are sent to a storage queue.

Azure Storage Queues tries its best to implement `First-In-First-Out (FIFO)` but there are no guarantees for that.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, thanks for reply. My doubt was is it possible to enqueue a message at the beginning of the queue (considering FIFO is happening properly) so that it gets picked up at the earliest after enqueue?

Comment: Assuming the queue is empty, then the message will be picked up as soon as ta consumer polls the queue for messages.

Comment: The will not be empty, there will be other jobs. The new ones which holds a higher priority than the existing ones, and should be picked before them, is what I am trying to solve...one way would be adding invisibility to the existing ones but that has a risk of setting high value where the jobs will sit idle even after the high priority ones are done.

Comment: One possible solution would be to use multiple queues. High priority jobs could go in a different queue and normal priority jobs could go in a different one. You could poll high priority jobs queue more frequently than the normal priority jobs queue.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. That's what we too have planned till now. :)

Comment: Can you offer a link to MS documentation where they explain that FIFO is not a guarantee?

Comment: @WillD - 2nd paragraph here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/queue-service-rest-api - `Messages are generally added to the end of the queue and retrieved from the front of the queue, although first in, first out (FIFO) behavior is not guaranteed.`